# echo expect script is non-deterministic

Tags: expect

The following expect / code pair only works sometimes:

1. Simple cpp echo program:

   ```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       string buffer;
       while (1)
       {
           getline(cin, buffer, '\n');
           if (cin.eof())
               break;
           cout<<buffer<<endl;
       }
       return 0;
    }
   ```
2. Expect script

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/expect

   spawn ./echo

   exp_internal 1

   set timeout 1

   send "a\n"
   expect {
       -re {^a\r\n$}
   }
   ```
3. Success match:

   ```
   spawn ./echo
   send: sending "a\n" to { exp6 }
   Gate keeper glob pattern for '^a\r\n$' is 'a
   '. Activating booster.

   expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "^a\r\n$"? Gate "a\r\n"? gate=no
   a

   expect: does "a\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "^a\r\n$"? Gate "a\r\n"? gate=yes re=yes
   expect: set expect_out(0,string) "a\r\n"
   expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
   expect: set expect_out(buffer) "a\r\n"
   ```
4. Failure match:

   ```
   spawn ./echo
   send: sending "a\n" to { exp6 }
   Gate keeper glob pattern for '^a\r\n$' is 'a
   '. Activating booster.

   expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "^a\r\n$"? Gate "a\r\n" gate=no
   a
   a

   expect: does "a\r\na\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "^a\r\n$"? Gate "a\r\n"? gate=yes re=no
   expect: timed out
   ```

I don't understand why on some runs I get the double line "a", and some runs I get the single one? I would have assumed the expect hooks up spawned process such that **send** will pipe everything to stdin and **expect** gets everything from stdout.

Any clarifications would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your tty have echo enabled. In your first case you send `a\n` and your program read it and return `a\n` but expect did read before std::cout is flushed so the buffer contain only `a\n`. In the other case it read and send didn't finished so it read nothing and the second run it does read and your std::cout was flushed before. So you read two times. You could modify your program to output something else (like with a prefix) or add a dummy `expect "<non existing string>"` as last instruction so you force to drain stdout.

```
$ ./expect.sh
spawn ./echo
send: sending "a\n" to { exp6 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '^a\r\n$' is 'a
'. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "^a\r\n$"? Gate "a\r\n"? gate=no
a

expect: does "a\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "^a\r\n$"? Gate "a\r\n"? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "a\r\n"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "a\r\n"

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "<non existing string>"? no
a

expect: does "a\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "<non existing string>"? no
expect: timed out
```

To fix the root cause you can first disabling echo with `stty -echo` and then spawn with option `-nottyinit` used like this `spawn -nottyinit ./echo` because

> -nottyinit skips the "sane" initialization

An alternative way is to set `set stty_init -echo` then spawn

https://github.com/aeruder/expect/blob/ce11b8121e6900888d137fec0b990bd1484cbb7c/pty_unicos.c#L147-L155 here is where tty is setup. `stty_init` is applied after tty sane. So it might be a preferred method.